# What are the differences between Jacobson's "Basic Algebra" and "Lectures in Abstract Algebra"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Nathan Jacobson's books "Basic Algebra I, II" and "Lectures in Abstract Algebra - Volumes I, II, III (GTM 30, 31, 32)". What are the differences between these two books?

1) The subject.

The material of the two books overlap, which one is better?

2) Does "Lectures in Abstract Algebra" aim to undergraduate?

3) "Basic Algebra I, II" Cannot edit a word! Really?

4) Is it necessary to read the two books?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm afraid that your question isn't clear on what it's asking. It could be about differences in subject matter, the level of the books, which one has better proofs, which one is better as a reference work, and so on. Please [edit] your question to specify in what respect you would like to compare these books.

Comment: I find Basic Algebra much easier to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than directly answer your question (which I don't have time to do now, and others are probably more qualified anyway), I thought I would mention that you might be able to get some useful insight by looking at book reviews of the later-published Jacobson texts. Here are three reviews that I know of:

Darrell Eugene Haile, **Mathematical Intelligencer** 3 #4 (1981), 188-189. [doi:10.1007/BF03022984](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03022984)

Kenneth Paul Bogart, **American Mathematical Monthly** 92 #10 (December 1985), 743-745. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323244)

Andy Roy Magid, **American Mathematical Monthly** 93 #8 (October 1986), 665-667. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322348)

Answer (score 18):

The *Basic* texts are much more modern in content and organization than the *Lectures*. The *Lectures* are based on Jacobson's graduate lectures on algebra at Johns  Hopkins and Yale in the 1940's and early 1950's-consequently, the style is far more classical and categorical/homological methods are nearly completely missing. *Basic*  also covers quite a bit more than the *Lectures*. That being said, the *Lectures* are very careful and comprehensive and it's interesting to compare the 2 via the state of the field in the different time frames if you can get a copy relatively cheap.

Answer (score 2):

I second Mathemagician1234's response. Lectures in Abs. Alg. were one of those wonderful old-school treatments in the spirit of Herstein's Topics in Algebra - elegantly readable and lacking in more modern tools like categories and functors. For those of us who've had trouble crossing that bridge, that can be a strength. On the other hand, Basic Alg. doesn't seem to use much in the way of homological methods until Vol. 2, and a glance there suggests that his introduction there is relatively chatty, example-driven, and user-friendly as usual.