# Series for Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

Abstract Algebra seems to be a huge topic that I'd like to study in some depth.  Is there some series of books on algebra that starts from an (upper-division) undergrad level and includes a fairly *comprehensive* subject list -- including (amongst all the basics like groups/ rings/ fields) introductions to topics like algebras over fields/ rings, lattices, homological algebras, algebraic geometry, topological algebra, etc?

I'm looking for a *series* of books in the same vein as Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry* and the *Princeton Lectures on Analysis*.

If no such good series exists for abstract algebra, is Dummit/ Foote the most comprehensive single textbook that you guys know of?  I'm looking to spend a year or two going through the material so it doesn't matter if it's really long.

Comment: You could try Serge Lang's book

Comment: Jacobson has a famous 3-volume series "Lectures in Abstract Algebra". These are probably dated (1950-60s), but I have heard good things about them.

Comment: Do not try Lang unless you like correcting errors and filling gaps in proofs :)

Comment: Rotman's 1000-page "Advanced Modern Algebra" might cover a lot of what you want your series to do.

Comment: Bourbaki's 2-volume algebra

Comment: Maybe Knapp, "Basic Algebra" and "Advanced Algebra". I've only glanced at them, but there is a lot of material packed into those two volumes.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Apparently the new edition of Rotman is being split into two volumes, so it will count as a bona fide series.

Comment: @Bungo My plan for now is to finish going through Artin's Algebra and then start on Knapp's books.

Comment: I think I have a book called _A Book of Abstract Algebra_ at home.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Algebra by IN Herstein.

Answer (score 0):

There is the two-volume set *Basic Algebra* by Jacobson.

They have been reprinted by Dover:
[volume 1](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486471896.html) and
[volume 2](http://store.doverpublications.com/048647187x.html).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523289/what-are-the-differences-between-jacobsons-basic-algebra-and-lectures-in-abs.